# Скорость операций mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Известно, что если на поле, по которому часто делать `SELECT` повесить индекс типа `INDEX`, то выборка из базы будет происходить в разы быстрее. Но так же на форумах пишут, что вместе с этим увеличивается время `INSERT`, `UPDATE` запросов, т.к. необходимо обновлять индекс. Это все понятно и претензий нет. :)

Вопрос в том, увеличивается ли время `INSERT`, `UPDATE` запросов, если поле, на котором установлен индекс типа `INDEX`, в процессе этих запросов не изменяется?

P.S. Надеюсь, суть вопроса понятна :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, потому что индекс - это не одно поле, а связка полей. Если хоть что-то в связке меняется, индекс обновляется. То что в квартире 123 живет теперь не Иванов, а Петров заставит изменить кучу документов.

Правда для большинства проектов разница незначительна.
Проверить легко: создайте таблицу с 10к записями. И посмотрите среднее время указанных операций при одном/двум/трем индексами

Comment: А если выполняется INSERT и данные добавляются в конец таблицы, то индексы пересчитываются сначала или просто обновляются с "добавлением в конец индекса"? (индекс по-прежнему типа INDEX)

Comment: добавляются. Аналогично новой записи в телефонном справочнике.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!